# convert dataset to datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

```
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(
  @"select Time1, Time2, EndDate from Event 
    where Venue ='" + txtVenue.Text + "', 
    StartDate ='" + cbStartMonth.Text + "/" + 
    cbStartDay.Text + "/" + 
    DateTime.Today.Year + "'" ,conn);
da.Fill(dt);
```

i'm sorry for the confusion, the code actually works but the problem is now how to view data coming from the data table

Comment: Are you sure there is more than one record that matches? Also, shouldn't `ds.Tables.Add(dt);` be *after* the datatable is filled?

Comment: You should make your question clearer.

Answer (score 2):

A `DataSet` is a collection of `DataTable`s. You don't convert from one to the other, one stores the other.

If only 1 row is showing up, then your `Sql` is only returning a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Just you adjust with `.Tables property`

```
var result = yourDataSet.Tables[0];
```

Your table is empty because you can adjust your query with and between clauses

But you rewrite your query `( You add and operator)`

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Time1, Time2, EndDate from Event 
where Venue ='" + txtVenue.Text + "' AND 
StartDate ='" + cbStartMonth.Text + "/" + 
cbStartDay.Text + "/" + 
DateTime.Today.Year + "'" ,conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also change your code to use parameters. Otherwise you are leaving yourself open for serious SQL injection attacks all over the place.

Look here for an example of how to use parameters with your SqlDataAdapter.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.71).aspx

It also answers your question.

HTH
SR

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
ds.Table.Add(dt);
    DataTable dt1=ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: A bit of an explanation would have been great.